# Reactjs render script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

What I want is to add here one script and when it will ReactDom.render, add it to the dom and... run it too. But it doesnt run it even tho i can see it in the dom. This is a piece of code, I am using the reactdom.render in another file.

```
var React = require('react');
var List = require('./list.js');
var Header = React.createClass({
render:function(){
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <List/>
            <input id='keywords' type='text' placeholder='SEARCH' name="keyword" maxLength="30" />
            <button title='Search' alt='Search Button' />
            <script src='./scripts/jquery/send_keyword.js' ></script>
        </div>
        );
}
});
module.exports = Header;
```

I tried to use the 'src' both from this file perspective  (../jquery/send_keyword.js) and from my index.php perspective (like in the example above).
PS: When I add it directly from index.php the javascript file is running but I try to have the index.php file clear so I add html things with reactjs to practice it.... something missing herE???

Comment: Try and specify the script source within {} as  `<script src={'./scripts/jquery/send_keyword.js'} ></script>`

Comment: the {} will execute the code inside as javacript but will it find the code if i just put the path?? Second in which perspective way should i put the path , from the file im writing the code or from the index.php file??

Comment: You should write the path relative to the current file, i.e the file containing you Header component

Comment: i will try it later and i will write if it worked

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I used the script through the index.php and not render it from reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Though i don't recommend rendering a script this should work:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = './scripts/jquery/send_keyword.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```